# Jenkins build error for a maven test project on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: maven, ubuntu, jenkins

I am encountering the error below while running a maven test project on Ubuntu 16.04. When I run the project from the terminal it works fine. But I need to run it through Jenkins now. 
I have given all permissions for jenkins user. I cannot seem to understand the reason for this error so that I can troubleshoot further. Can someone please help as I am new to Devops and learning?

## Console Output

```
`EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Maven Test Parsing POMs                      Established TCP socket on 43944 [IceScrum] $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle    //bin/java -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven33-agent-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar:/usr/share/maven/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main /usr/share/maven/ /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-3.10.2.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven33-interceptor-1.12-alpha-1.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.12-alpha-1.jar 43944 <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started Executing Maven:  -B -f /opt/IceScrum/pom.xml verify [INFO] Scanning for projects...`

`[WARNING] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ cxm7 --- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /opt/IceScrum/src/main/resources [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ cxm7 --- [INFO] No sources to compile [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ cxm7 --- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /opt/IceScrum/src/test/resources [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ cxm7 --- [INFO] No sources to compile [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ cxm7 --- [INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /opt/IceScrum/target/surefire-reports`

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project cxm7: Error creating properties files for forking: Permission denied -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[JENKINS] Archiving /opt/IceScrum/pom.xml to cxm/cxm7/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/cxm7-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
/opt/IceScrum/pom.xml is not inside /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Maven Test/opt/IceScrum/; will archive in a separate pass [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE`
```

After I ran the script with -X switch. I got the following results.

`Apache Maven 3.3.9`
`Maven home: /usr/share/maven`
`Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle Corporation Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-101-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"`
`[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml`
`[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /root/.m2/settings.xml [DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from /usr/share/maven/conf/toolchains.xml[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from /root/.m2/toolchains.xml [DEBUG] Using local repository at /root/.m2/repository [DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /root/.m2/repository [INFO] Scanning for projects`
``` [DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:pom:1: (none) [DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] [INFO]``[INFO] BUILD FAILURE``[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/cyberadmin). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]org.apache.maven.lifecycle.MissingProjectException: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/cyberadmin). ``` `Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException`

Comment: And have you tried running maven with the `-e` or `-X` switch, just as the log tells you to do?

Comment: @DavidStockinger

Comment: Justin, did you mean to write anything other than my name?

Comment: I am sorry. I tried to edit the comment, but failed. So i have updated my post above. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Your Jenkins setup either is running with a wrong user or you initially ran it with jenkins (installation user) user then with the root user which leads to "Permission denied" errors... Or even you have set up the jenkins to use folders that the user running the application does not have permission to access.

Comment: @Jorge Campos How can i rectify this? I have provided jenkins user full permission below root. Still i receive the same error.

Comment: Well, you have to change the owner of the files. The problem is that once you run it with the wrong user (at some point) this wrong user created files (which belongs to it) now that you are running with the proper user some files belongs to that other user therefore the permission error. I would change all files from the jenkins structure to the jenkins user using the `chown jenkins:jenkins -R` in the jenkins folder.

Comment: i am running this on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: i will try that and will let you know, i appreciate your help on this.

Comment: I solved it. I provided chmod 777 to the pom.xml directory. Atleast i got the script to run.